# Using stargazer with panelAR

Tags: r, time-series, stargazer

Is it possible to export regression tables created with the `panelAR` package using `stargazer`? When I try I get

> % Error: Unrecognized object type.

Creating a data frame first would probably do the trick, but as I am fairly new to R I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: The `texreg` package also creates latex and html tables from R model output. It does not support `panelAR`, but `texreg` *does* have built-in means for creating custom extract functions to extend `texreg` to new model types. How to do this is explained in Section 6 of [this introduction to `texreg`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwi19rCP2pPJAhUT6WMKHZSpAb8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Farticle%2Fview%2Fv055i08%2Fv55i08.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHAcj3C-TovzqkOpDSLu08z4udiRg&sig2=DHXOaNixxBnzmFpe_G-XTQ).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you can't use the `stargazer` package to create tables when you use `panelAR`.

This reason for this, as the error message suggest, is that `stargazer` does not support objects whose class is `panelAR`.  See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf for a comprehensive list of the model supported by `stargazer`

R is an object oriented language, since you are new to R you might find it advantageous to better understand what is meant by this.

Loosely speaking, object oriented means that everything in R is an object.  Each object has metadata attached to it.  Arguably the most important piece of metadata is the object's class.  To determine an object's class, you can call the `class` function.  Again loosely speaking, when you pass an object to a function, the function will usually first consider what class the object has and then preform the necessary analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jacob. Do you know if it is possible to manually create a data frame which works with stargazer? Eventually, are there any other packages which can handle panelAR regression models?

Comment: @M.I. I'm not sure what you mean by creating a data frame which works with `startgazer`.  As for other packages you might want to look at the `xtable` packages, though it does not easily reproduce nice results like `stargazer` does.  It might also be easier to consider a different packages than `panelAR`.  The `stargazer` packages supports numerous packages which may be able to do the same thing as the `panelAR` package.